# ALSA volume lower after reboot

Tags: raspbian, alsa, pulseaudio

My ALSA sound volume gets mysteriously reset every time I do a reboot.

I set the default ALSA volume to 100% with `amixer cset numid=3 100%`. Then I do a reboot and check my amixer volume again and suddenly it's at 91%, or 87%, etc. I tried to store the current setting with `sudo alsactl store`, but that didn't help either.

Does that sound familiar to anyone? What could change the volume during the reboot process?

My system: Raspbian Wheezy, pulseaudio, and I start mplayer on @reboot via crontab.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to mention your sound card number to store the settings using `sudo alsactl store`,

You could see the card number of your device using the command,

```
arecord -l
```

The output would be apparaently in this form,

> List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices
>
> card 1: U0x41e0x30d3 [USB Device 0x41e:0x30d3], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
>
> Subdevices: 1/1
>
> Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

**card 1**, in the above output indicating the number of your card.

Now, In order to save the settings that you have modified in card 1,

```
sudo alsactl store 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it for my card number 0 and then did a reboot, but the amixer volume was different again. Went from 100% to 91%.